# The primorial version of $e^x$

Tags: power-series, primorial

What values of $x$ does the sum of this type:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n\#}$$

converge for? 
(where $n\#$ is the product of all primes less or equal to $n$)

Comment: This converges even faster than the usual exponential, so it certainly converges for all values of $x$.

Comment: @WhatsUp No, n# is the product of all primes less or equal to n, so n#<n! for large values. I know that n# grows like $e^(1+o(1))n$ , so I think it will start to diverge for some value around e=2.718...

Comment: Alright, then you should SAY what $n\#$ means. I automatically thought it was the product of first $n$ prime numbers.

Comment: Do you know the prime number theorem? If so, it may help to note that $n\# = \exp \bigl(\vartheta(n)\bigr)$, where $\vartheta$ is the first Chebyshev function.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Thank you. I  know both the PNT and the relation between the first Chebyshev function and primorials. But I couldn't answer the question using that. I will appreciate anything you can also share.

Comment: Do you know the Cauchy–Hadamard formula? That in conjunction with the PNT answers the question. (Except for the question of whether the series converges at some point of the boundary of the disk of convergence. To answer that question [negatively] one must know a bit more about $\vartheta$ than just the plain PNT).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\ln p_n\#\sim n\ln n\sim p_n$, $\ln n\#\sim n$ and $\ln\left|\frac{x^n}{n\#}\right|=n\ln|x|-\ln n\#\sim n(\ln|x|-1)$. This implies the radius of convergence of your series is $e$.

Comment: Thank you. Can we know exactly what is the interval that the series converges for? And if we could, how would we calculate the integral of the series from a to b; where a and b are the bounds of the interval of convergence?